# Forms inside a Panel

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I am building a Windows application using C# in which there's a Panel (with a background image on it) which can host forms. Each form contains an picturebox with an image (chosen by the user), 4 labels and 4 buttons. When I am moving the forms over the Panel I am experiencing flickering and this happens specially when the forms go outside the edges of the Panel.

I have tried double buffering and setstyles but flickering is still present. In the link you can see the situation in which it happens, as I said above: the form has been moved outside the edges of the Panel (http://postimage.org/image/qgmad2ey9/).

Comment: Sounds like the background is being part-invalidated. Can you try with a panel instead of a window form; i.e. click and drag a panel around to see if you get the same behavior. I'm thinking because you have multiple forms in an MDI setup, you have a discontinuity between invalidation and redraw

Comment: Sure. Let me adjust the code and I'll return you back! Thanks

Comment: Well, I have tried with a Panel and a BackgroundImage in it. The Panel is inside the main Panel and it is not customized (i.e. no SetStyle). When I am moving it, the movement is not fluid. Flickering is still present. (http://postimage.org/image/xy5k5g3tl/). Thanks

Comment: Just to complement: once again the flickering is heavier when the smaller Panel (the one inside the main Panel) is moving out from the edges of the main Panel. It seems that when I move it again totally inside the main Panel, it is completely re-drawn.

Comment: http://youtu.be/mHiNE0zvxv0